# How do i send ical through mail in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to send a .ics file with mail now what shoud i change in may code please suggest. am able to send simple mail. I use some references but they give me only how to create cal file and how to send with mime part file but i want to send it with zend mail. If its not possible then suggest other code/references for used.......

```
// ical Statr

                $timestamp = date('Ymd') . 'T' . date('His');
        $uid = md5($timestamp) . '@exemplo.com.br';
        $dtCreated = date('Ymd') . 'T' . date('His');
        $dtStart = '20110701T080000';
        $dtEnd = '20110701T124500';
        $eventSubject = 'Booking';
        $eventDescription = 'Party';
        $location = 'Pune';

        $ical = <<<ICALENDAR_DATA
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Product/Platform/Name//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:{$dtStart}
DTEND:{$dtEnd}
DTSTAMP:{$timestamp}
UID:{$uid}
SUMMARY:{$eventSubject}
DESCRIPTION:{$eventDescription}
CREATED:{$dtCreated}
LAST-MODIFIED:{$dtCreated}
LOCATION:{$location}
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:xyz@gmail.com
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:My cal request
TRIGGER:-P0DT0H10M0S
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
ICALENDAR_DATA;

        // ical end
        $To = 'mujahed69@gmail.com';
        $Subject = "hello";
        $Body = "welcome";
        $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
        $config = $config['settings']['EMAIL'];

        $mail = new \Zend\Mail\Message();
        $mail->setFrom($config['FROM'], $config['NAME']);
        $mail->addTo($To); //, $Params['CustomerName']
        $mail->setSubject($Subject);

        $bodyPart = new \Zend\Mime\Message();
        $bodyMessage = new \Zend\Mime\Part($Body);
        $bodyMessage->type = 'text/html';
        $bodyPart->setParts(array($bodyMessage));

        $mail->setBody($bodyPart);
        $mail->setEncoding('UTF-8');
        //$mail->getHeaders()->get('content-type')->setType('multipart/alternative');
        $transport = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
        $result = $transport->send($mail);
```

Comment: Have you seen this already? http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.attachments.html

Comment: Yes but when i use this code at  given Fatal error in following line
$mail = new Zend_Mail();

Error is

<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Main\Controller\Zend_Mail' not found in <b>/var/www/html/restaurant/module/Main/src/Main/Controller/ReservationController.php</b> on line <b>130</b><br />

Comment: What version of Zend are you using? and can you please show me the code that return that error

Comment: 1. Zend Framework 2 
Error posted on above comment

Comment: Hope this will help you http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mail.attachments.html

Comment: No boss its not working...

Comment: Thanks for your great help....but its not solved yet

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: $text = new Mime\Part() at this line....Fatal error Part() not found

Comment: Thanks for support.......

Comment: Do you have this "Use Zend\Mime, Zend\Mail\Message;"?